# Spring Data JPA, how to one attribute map to two columns?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

Suppose I have "Account" entity class, and "Transaction" entity class. In table, detail is:

| transfer_id | account_from_id | account_to_id | money |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 565 | 1 | 2 | 12 |
| 566 | 3 | 1 | 15 |

So what annotation or how to code Account entity class, so when I get account.getTransactions, for account_id = 1, it will has 2 transactions? (because both transfer entity involves account id = 1)

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Account {
     // ...
     
     //TODO: How should I do here? Use which annotation or how to do?
     private Set<Transfer> transfers;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to map "from" and "to" transfers separately:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Account {
     @OneToMany
     @JoinColumn(name = "account_from_id")
     private Set<Transfer> fromTransfers;

     @OneToMany
     @JoinColumn(name = "account_to_id")
     private Set<Transfer> toTransfers;
}
```

But if you need both in one mapped collection you can try something like:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Account {
     @OneToMany
     @JoinFormula("select ts.id from transfer ts where account_from_id = ts.id or account_to_id = ts.id )
     private Set<Transfer> transfers;

}
```